# Writing to an imported Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have imported a JS file that purely is used to contain data. I want to be able to push changes to the data file, is this possible client / browser side only or do I need to use PHP / Python / Node?
`<script src="datafile.js"></script>`
Data File Contents:

```
var data = {"someValue":{"someOtherValue": "yeah"},
"anotherValue": [{"key": "value"},{"key": "value"}]}
```

Comment: Push changed as in 'update the file for later use'? Because, no, you cannot. That would be an immense security issue if you could just do that. You could put the data in something like LocalStorage and then read it from there if available, but actually amending a file on the server would require the server to update it - and preferably in a secure, authenticated way if you don't want to get hacked. Never trust user input.

Comment: You can do it but that data won't be available after reload or for another client. If you wan't to persist it you will need to make some tool that will accept that data and append it to the original file

Comment: This is what server-side is for, among others to manage and update files on the server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in brief to answer my own question based off the answers here:

1. Editing a file via a client side language is impossible and would
   pose a security threat to the server.
2. If I would like to update the data in the file I will need to use a server side language as I have mentioned. PHP is what I will
   be using in my case. My html file will just become a .php and will
   listen for `$_GET['idToChangeInJSONFile']`.
3. Another option is that I could store the data in localStorage and be able to manipulate from there. This however is not consistent
   and would get cleared when a different browser is used or the
   browser is reset.